# Order dataset according to given list

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

I have a dataset `dt` that I would like to be ordered according to `listCountriesOrdered` & `col` in alphabetic order

```
library(data.table)  
countries<- c("AT","BE","BG","DE","CY")
listCountriesOrdered <- c("BE","BG","DE","AT","CY")
col <- c("A","C","B")
dt <- CJ(countries, col)
```

later on I want to do `left_join` with values and keep the right ordering

Comment: What does the function `CJ` do? And which package is it coming from?

Comment: @bird it is from data.table, they are just creating an example object dt.

Comment: What is the dataset you try to sort?

Comment: Provide the 2nd data.table object that you are trying to merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `match`:

```
dt[order(match(countries,listCountriesOrdered),col)]

    countries col
 1:        BE   A
 2:        BE   B
 3:        BE   C
 4:        BG   A
 5:        BG   B
 6:        BG   C
 7:        DE   A
 8:        DE   B
 9:        DE   C
10:        AT   A
11:        AT   B
12:        AT   C
13:        CY   A
14:        CY   B
15:        CY   C
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard tool to do this in R is factors:

```
dt[, countries := factor(countries, levels = listCountriesOrdered)]
setorder(dt, countries)

#     countries col
#  1:        BE   A
#  2:        BE   B
#  3:        BE   C
#  4:        BG   A
#  5:        BG   B
#  6:        BG   C
#  7:        DE   A
#  8:        DE   B
#  9:        DE   C
# 10:        AT   A
# 11:        AT   B
# 12:        AT   C
# 13:        CY   A
# 14:        CY   B
# 15:        CY   C
```